# is it necessary to recall macros in public parts of inheriting class in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, macros

I want to use the Eigen library for a program and have a class hierarchy that employs Eigen fixed matrix size members. According to the Eigen documentation, this makes it necessary to 16 byte align the classes. Eigen provides a macro to do that, however since I am inheriting, I am unsure whether said behaviour occurs only in the base class.

I.e.

```
class A{
    public :
        EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
        // member definitions
};
```

do I have to specify use of the macro anew?

```
class B : public A{
    public:
       EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
       // definitions of B
};
```

or is it sufficient to leave out the macro in the definition of B?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075375/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it is not necessary to use the `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` macro, since the `operator new` defined by `class A` is inherited by `B`.

On the other hand, it does not really hurt either and in some situations it may actually be safer to just put the macro in every class which itself has aligned Eigen member variables.