# Eigen instance containing another instance holding a fixed-size eigen object

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I 've just read the [Structures having static members](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html) eigen page. The latter states the following:

> If you define a structure having members of fixed-size vectorizable Eigen types, you must overload its "operator new" so that it generates 16-bytes-aligned pointers. Fortunately, Eigen provides you with a macro EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW that does that for you.

However it's not clear to me whether we should also use the `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` macro for class instances that hold other class instances which in turn hold the fixed-size containers?

For example, in class A of the followin snippet, is the EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW needed?

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

class B
{
public:
  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;
  Eigen::Vector2d v;
};

class A
{
public:
  B b;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  B* b = new B(); // this should have no alignement problems as we use EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
  A* a = new A(); // how about this one?

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it is needed in both `A` and `B`. If `A` would inherit from `B` it would also inherit the `new` operator (thus making it not necessary to write again). Also, if `B` itself would never be allocated directly, but just as part of `A`, you would need the `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` only in `A`.

Also, if you compile for a x86_64 architecture your program will also very likely work, since most compilers will always 16byte-align the result of `new`, on the other hand, just adding `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` everywhere will barely have a performance impact (unless you excessively (de-)allocate objects).

Comment: Wow, surprised to hear that. I thought it would be the other way around since Eigen is so widely used and there is nothing I found on this use-case of EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other way around"?

Comment: I thought you wouldn't need to add the EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR in class A as well.

Comment: Well, you do. Unless, `A` would inherit from `B`. If membership of an aligned variable would be sufficient to get an aligned `new` operator, there would be no need at all for the macro.